# Can Object Hashes be passed to *_tag functions in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some trouble trying to inject a helper tooltip function into a submit_tag function in rails. From what I have seen I could statically pass in an object hash to the submit_tag function, but when I try to use another function to return something it doesn't work. I realize that I can also not use the object hash and just pass in `class: , and title:`. But it'd be easier to include everything I need in a function.

So with the static object hash:

```
button_tag type: 'submit', { class: "btn btn-default", title: "Check", data: { toggle: "tooltip", placement: "top"} }
```

With the function:

`button_tag type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default", tooltip("Check")`

```
    def tooltip(title, placement="top")
      { title: title, data: { toggle: "tooltip", placement: placement, template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner right-tooltip-widen"></div></div>' } } 
    end
```

I'm new to ruby & rails, so I'm not sure if I am missing something obvious or not. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to merge in any additional options into a unified options hash:

```
button_tag type: 'submit', tooltip("Check").merge(class: "btn ban-default")
```

Ruby treats your two options as separate hashes. It's worth noting that markup languages like HAML *will* automatically merge them for you.